# I don't see my table

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a frame with table, combobox, I want to fill the table with data from database by combobox, but if I use with itemlistener I don't see the table, without itemlistener and `String sql="select * from Arlista"` then I see my table with data.
(combob=combobox)

**edit:** now I get error for main, "modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

```
 public static class TableFromDatabase extends JFrame
{           Vector columnNames = new Vector();
            Vector data = new Vector();
            String [] asd={"Arlista"};
            JComboBox combob=new JComboBox(asd);

             String tesztvalt2;
    public  TableFromDatabase() {

        combob.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            @Override
            public  void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
                tesztvalt2=(combob.getSelectedItem()).toString();
         if (e.getItem().equals(tesztvalt2)) {
                try {

            String url="jdbc:sqlserver://FARKAS-PC;databaseName=Mozi;integratedSecurity=true;";
            String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"; 
            Class.forName( driver );
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url );  

            String sql = "Select * from "+tesztvalt2+"";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
            }


            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.addElement( row );
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println( ex );
        }


        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)getContentPane();
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }
            }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableFromDatabase frame = new TableFromDatabase();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
        }); 
                }         
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied from [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) was just designed to show the basics of how to invoke the SQL and create a JTable and add it to a frame BEFORE the frame is visible. This means that the `pack()` method in that code will invoke the layout manager so the new created table will have a valid size.

You are attempting to dynamically create a JTable on a visible GUI. So you can't just add the table/scrollpane to the frame. You also need to revalidate() all the components. The basic code would be:

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel)getContentPane();
panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```